# When booting I sometimes get "No bootable device..." , sometimes it works

Tags: windows, bios, boot

It says like, i should check my motherboard-handbook or something. I press ctrl-alt-del and it works again. Yesterday i got an only "Bootfailure" with "Press a key" , next restart it works again...

Is this a strong indicator that my mother board is going down? I have checked the boot device settings my harddisk has the highest priority, and its an 4 year old dell with an windows xp installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that your hard disk is taking longer to start up than your motherboard.   Try setting your hard disk to the lowest priority to give your hard disk the time to "wake up" after any other peripherals you have attached.

I get this problem when I try to tweak my bios to improve boot times....